# Change background color elements in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

Pagination functionality: I want to change background color if a user clicks any element in the array. I am able to achieve this with code below but when I click other elements in this array I want the element that was previously clicked and the remaining elements to use original `pagins` class. Can someone point me in the direction?

```css
.pagins a {
 color: #fff;
 background-color:#009de0;
}

.testClass {
 background-color:#fff !important;
 color:#009de0 !important;
}
```

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('pagins');
$.each(elements, function(){
    $(elements).click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('testClass');
    });
})
```

Comment: Note that you should remove the `$.each` call. Your `each` loop makes no sense. jQuery `click` method itself iterates through the collection. You are currently binding multiple click handler for each element which is pointless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `$.each()`, which is a way of looping in jQuery.  You will end up calling the click handler multiple times per click.

You are using jQuery, so don't use `document.getElementsByClassName('pagins')`.  Just use `$('.pagins')`.

Sounds like you only want the most recently clicked `.pagins` element to have the `testClass` class.  So, remove the class from all `.pagins.testClass` elements before adding the class to the clicked element.

```
$('.pagins').click(function(){
    $('.pagins.testClass').removeClass('testClass');
    $(this).addClass('testClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `testClass` from all elements before adding it to the selected element.

```
  $.each(elements, function(){
        $(elements).click(function() {
            $(elements).removeClass('testClass');      
            $(this).addClass('testClass');                                          
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('pagins');
$.each(elements, function(){
    $(elements).click(function(){
        $.each(elements, function() {$(this).removeClass('testClass')});
        $(this).addClass('testClass');                                          
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your code a bit you could do this -

```
$(".testClass").removeClass("testClass");
$(".pagins").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('testClass');
});
```

As supplying a class selector will apply the click function to all elements with that class.